# Making real URLs smaller

Tags: url, hash

This started off as a way to troll my friend but I've kind of gotten interested in this. I wanted to link my friend to a site called stupidtester.com but make it seem like a YouTube video so I researched online how to obfuscate a URL.

After some reasearch I made this:

https://www.youtube.crmwatchv=i4wiZ4fZIDo@%73%74%75%70%69%64%74%65%73%74%65%72.com

I learned I had to take the `o` out of `com` and I couldn't use `?` after `watch?`. My first question is why that is.

Secondly, I was wondering if there is a way to make the link even shorter somehow. Forgive me if this sounds stupid, but something like hashing or encrypting the URL so the browser understands the link but to the person clicking it it will look like a normal YouTube video. I ask because my friend said it looked too unrealistic to be a YouTube video.

Comment: You realise that hovering over the link displays its true purpose.

Comment: Do you mean if you type in the browser, it shows the true thing? Cause then yeah I noticed. Like I said it started as a joke, but I got really into it, so I just want to know how this stuff works and what's possible with it

Comment: you can  try  URL rewriting methods by hosting servers like IIS

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried  [this one](https://goo.gl/)

This is googles URL Shortner

Comment: Thank you! Do you know how it works or at least the reasoning behind it?

Comment: Everything is on StackOverflow Bro refer this Link http://stackoverflow.com/a/4572758/3583859