# MVC - load an image on the page from a "shortened" code on my domain (like Bit.ly does with links)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http, razor, url-shortener

I have http://example.com/Image/Show/CwYDBw8LDww where example.com is my site, Show is a method in the Image controller, the unique id CwYDBw8LDww is a key in a database which will point to some other URL on a different domain, e.g. a "hosted" image on Google.

The reason for doing this is that the URLs can get horribly long and unwieldy. I am storing the site content as Markdown/HTML and want to be able to write things like:

```
<p>Here is an image of a cat.</p>    
<img src="http://example.com/Image/Show/CwYDBw8LDww">
```

and have it render the page as if I put:

```
<img src="http://googleusercontent.com/SomeReallyReallyReallyLongImageURL.jpg">
```

So in the database there is a table entry with values:("CwYDBw8LDww", "http://googleusercontent.com/SomeReallyLongImageURL.jpg") which is how I know which "really long URL" belongs to the short code.

I know how to (e.g.) print the 'google' URL to the screen by getting an Action to return it, I am already able to talk to the database, etc. The part I'm missing is getting `/Images/Show?shortcode=CwYDBw8LDww` to bring back the Google image in a way that it can be rendered on the page. And whether I should be doing that in the View, or what.

My View currently has something like:

```
@Html.Raw(@Model.ArticleContent)
```

where the content is already stored as `<p>Here is an image of a cat</p>` etc.

Comment: I've answered the question myself as I've now got it working. I had got hung up on it being an "image" I embed in a web page, rather than a page redirect at 'top level' i.e. page the browser shows in the address bar etc. Once I'd stepped back and realised a HTTP request is really just a request whatever the "type" of the response I solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself with a bit of patience and research! I added the following to my Image controller.

```
public RedirectResult Show(string shortcode)
{
    return Redirect(data.GetURL(shortcode));
}
```

where GetURL() is a method in my data access layer which asks the database for the "long" URL that applies to the shortcode. (I handle cases like if the shortcode doesn't exist in the `GetURL()` code, so `Show()` assumes it has been given a valid URL.)

This returns a 302 "Temporary Redirect" HTTP response to re-point the client to the 'new' (Google in my example) URL.

This [SO question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562367/how-do-short-urls-services-work) was helpful in getting to the concept I needed.